# Invalid data in index exception

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I got this exception when trying to create a repository object. I am not really sure how it came about. To fix it I deleted and re-cloned my remote. Is there a better way to deal with it?

```
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Invalid data in index - incorrect header signature
 at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)   
 at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_index(RepositorySafeHandle repo)
 at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.<.ctor>b__0()
 at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor(String path, RepositoryOptions options)
```

Comment: That's awesome you've been able to recover from this situation. However, I'm not sure there's enough context here to explain how the index got corrupted in the first place. Hence, I don't think one may provide you with an actual answer.

Comment: Ok I will just keep on plugging away and if this comes up again I will see if I can pinpoint it. I just wasn't sure if there is a know better way of handling corruption resulting in this exception.

Comment: Well, you cloud have reset the index. As in `git reset HEAD` or `repo.Reset('HEAD');`. This would have replaced the content of your index with the the tip of your current branch.

Comment: Great! We have the code running on a server and want to be as self healing as possible so this will work in most cases. However from the stack trace it appears this exception was thrown from the repository constructor so I am not sure if it is possible via libgit2sharp to reset the index in this specific case.

Comment: Oh, you're right! LibGit2Sharp ensures the index is valid before accepting to deal with the repo. One way to work around this would be to simply drop the ".git/index" file. LibGit2Sharp won't cringe that way.